# Magento EE, how to set up rule based product relation for upsell?

Tags: magento, magento-1.13

Can somebody help me for setting up rule based product relation for upsell product.

Suppose I have one SKU PROD1 and have 3 upsell manually defined say P1,P2,P3.
Now I created a rule to for SKU PROD1 to add 5 more matching SKU say PR1,PR2...PR5.

Can some body help me to set up a rule for this. And how I can check this rule in manage product section for product PROD1.

Please help me, I am new to this feature of magento EE.

Answer (score 0):

WHat is you rule to "link up" these product together?

For my experience on EE, i am using some attributes & category to create the rule.

e.g. i am selling books, then I will set the rule to relate all books with specific Author & publisher. However you cannot generalize the rule to related the books having "same" author.

You have to set a value for each rule.